# Why `fun(i)` is deduced as`fun<int&>` other than `fun<int>` since `i` is the type of `int` and not a reference indeed?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I understand that `i` is an lvalue and `5` is an rvalue indeed(i.e. `5` is unnamed).  I know how to use `template <typename T> void fun(T&& x);` and when to use it, but I still can't wrap my head around why `fun(i)` is deduced as`fun<int&>` other than `fun<int>` since `i` is the type of `int` and not a reference indeed?

**I know there are many questions about rvalue\lvalue and forward reference on SO, but my question is quite different. I have browsed many related answers, nobody has explained it in detail indeed.**

Here is the related code snippets:

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T&& x); 

int i;
fun(i); // deduce<int&>(int& &&) -> deduce<int&>(int&)
fun(5); // deduce<int>(int&&)
```

Answer (score 0):

> why `fun(i)` is deduced as `fun<int&>` other than `fun<int>` since `i` is the type of `int` and not a reference indeed?

The deduction result depends on not only argument's type, but also argument's [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

As the result, if the argument is lvalue, `T` would be deduced as `int&`, the function parameter is `int&` too. If the argument is rvalue, `T` would be deduced as `int`, the function parameter is `int&&`.

Note that both `i` and `0` are of type `int`. If value category is not considered then we can't distinguish them (and preserve the value category of function argument).